# Kafka Streams - Synchronization of commit vs Rocks DB delete

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

In the low level processor API, I wanted to delete a key from the store immediately after the corresponding value is forwarded to the downstream. In the event of a rebalance OR a commit failure, would the delete performed on the store rollback by itself OR stay permanently deleted?  If later, is there a way to synchronize the store delete vs commit.  Would the above behavior differ with cache enabled on the store vs not enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior is independent of caching, and if you run with "at-least-once" guarantee the store will not roll back.

If you need stricter guarantees you can enable "exactly-once" processing that will provide the synchronization with the store you ask for.